# how to set constraint layout width that inside toolbar to be match parent?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image]

I have a `toolbar`, and inside that `toolbar` I place `constraintlayout`. I want to set that `constraintlayout` width to `match_parent`. but as you can see in the image above, even though I have set the `layout_width` to be `match_parent`, but in the start (left side) it doesn't match the parent. you can see the blue outline box in that green toolbox, the left side is not match the parent.

because I want place some  views inside that `toolbar`, like `searchbar`, text etc. and it is hard to make it right in the center if `constraintlayout` width not `match_parent`.

here is the xml I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/top_toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            android:elevation="4dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                tools:context=".Fragments.Search.SearchFragment"
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_toolbar" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/destination_label_text_view"
                    tools:text="Text View"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>



        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graph"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"/>


    <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar_main_activity"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ContentInset` attribute to your `toolbar` like below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/top_toolbar"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:elevation="4dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            tools:context=".Fragments.Search.SearchFragment"
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_toolbar" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/destination_label_text_view"
                tools:text="Text View"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not an issue of `ConstraintLayout`

`toolbar` has default left & right margin

you can remove it by the following code

```
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
```